# Not able to figure out why Docker build command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am trying to build a Docker image with given below steps and try to run a docker build command to generate an image in Windows 10 machine. I am not getting any error or so for the steps I am following.
Can someone help me on below and also let me know if any details are required.

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm","run","start" ]
```

[Powershell Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lu4i.png)

Comment: From which port you want to use your application?

Comment: please add this like in your dockerfile `EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: That looks like a pretty routine Node Dockerfile.  Can you edit the question to include the actual error you're getting, in the question itself (not behind the link and not as an image)?

Comment: Hi,

StackOverflow is not allowing to me upload an image due to some policy for a new contributor. But thank you guys for your all help and now I am not facing any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `dockerfile` you are missing a port to expose which is important to communicate from container to outside of the world.

Add this line in your `dockerfile`

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

PS:

Your `dockerfile` should look like following. And place your dockerfile in the root directory of your project.

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm","run","start" ]
```

Comment: Hi Dupinder,

My issue has been resolve and I am exposing the port while running docker run -p 3000:3000 <image_id>

Comment: @HeetShah congratulations. Enjoy Happy Docker Happy Containers  Happy to help

Comment: can you please help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179379/not-able-to-figure-out-why-docker-compose-up-is-not-running-my-react-js-app/62179639#62179639

Comment: @HeetShah I answered your other question too, please verify and if this current problem issue is resolved then please vote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we copy a docker command, it also copies the "$" sign. Try removing the sign and build the image again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).